# sent emails are sometimes received without content

Tags: email

Sometimes when I sent emails I receive answers stating that my email was empty. It seems very random and so far I have not been able to reconstruct this problem (have tested it on Gmail, Yahoo, AOL, Outlook, Mozilla Thunderbird, ... to no avail). It seems that only my email signature and/or sometimes also just the beginning of my email is displayed.

I've checked for font problems and problems within the html code of the mail, etc.

Where should I start?

Here's some sample code of the template I use that seems to create this error at random:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>
      ...
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--[if !mso]>
<!-- -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!--
<![endif]-->
  <style>
    html, body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body style="width: 100%; margin: 0;">
    <table bgcolor="#0568a6" border="0" style="background-color:#0568a6;border-collapse:collapse;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:100%;max-width:600px;margin:0 auto">
            <div style="display:block;width:98%;max-width:588px;margin:0 auto;padding:3px 1%;background-color:#0568a6">
              <table bgcolor="#0568A6" align="center" style="background-color:#0568a6;border-collapse: collapse;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%">
                <!--[if mso]>
<table align="center" bgcolor="#0568A6" width="588" style="background-color:#0568a6;border-collapse:collapse;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:588px">
<![endif]-->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:block;width:100%;max-width:588px;margin:0 auto;padding:0;background-color:#0568a6">
        <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="125" height="26" border="0" align="right" style="float: right;border:0px !important" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!--[if mso]>
</table>
<![endif]-->
  </table>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" align="center" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="display: block; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; clear: both;">
          <div style="display: block; width:98%; max-width: 588px; margin: 0 auto; padding:35px 1% 28px; color: #111111;">
            <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
              <!--[if mso]>
<table align="center" width="588" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<![endif]-->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 0px 0px 4px 0px; width: 100%; max-width: 588px;">
        <p style="font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; color: #222222; margin-bottom: 15px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 13pt; line-height: 1.25;">
          Content
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--[if mso]>
</table>
<![endif]-->
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" align="center" bgcolor="#efefef" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="display: block; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; clear: both;">
          <div style="display: block; max-width: 588px;width:98%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 6px 1% 16px;">
            <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" bgcolor="#efefef">
              <!--[if mso]>
<table align="center" bgcolor="#efefef" width="588" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<![endif]-->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 0px 0px 4px 0px; width: 100%; max-width: 588px;">
        <p style="font-size: 8.5pt; color: #999999;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; line-height: 1.2; border: 0;">
          Footer
          <br>
          <br>
          <a target="_blank" href="%UNSUBSCRIBELINK%" style="font-size: 8.5pt; color: #278ac8 !important; line-height: 1.2; text-decoration: none; border: 0;font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;">
            <span style="color: #278ac8; text-decoration: none;">
              CLICK TO UNSUBSCRIBE
            </span>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe try something like [Litmus](https://putsmail.com/) to test it.

Comment: @mikeyq6 I tried Litmus earlier, not regularly though. I just did a test with the last mail that has given this problem and it came out good in all tested clients: Gmail, AOL, etc. What's weird to me is that about two months ago I got a complaint from someone with an AOL address but when I tested that exact message with my own AOL account it came out right. Could it be a browser-specific problem? Or something else I can't influence? What HTML element can cause such an issue? Maybe I can just remove it from any future mailings.

Comment: Can you get a copy of the blank emails? Maybe you can look at the source and see if there is any clue in there.

Comment: I've tried that but when a blank email is forwarded to me then the content shows up. It seems like some browser or provider doesn't render the content proberly or something. I've received screen shots already of the problem but when someone forwards it to me the content always shows for me. Also, I had some reports that the content showed to the receiver once they clicked on "reply"

Comment: @mikeyq6 thanks for your comments, it helped to further look and not give up. Below is the answer to the mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem. It seems to be a bug in (earlier) versions of IE (who guessed it...).

The key part of the problem is the 1% padding right and left in the DIV element that serves as a container.

```
  <body style="width: 100%; margin: 0;">
    <table bgcolor="#0568a6" border="0" style="background-color:#0568a6;border-collapse:collapse;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:100%;max-width:600px;margin:0 auto">


            // this DIV has right and left padding of 1% which causes a bug in IE
            <div style="display:block;width:98%;max-width:588px;margin:0 auto;padding:3px 1%;background-color:#0568a6">


              <table bgcolor="#0568A6" align="center" style="background-color:#0568a6;border-collapse: collapse;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%">
                <!--[if mso]>
                  ... and so on
```

The result was that in some mail clients (Gmail, AOL, Comcast, maybe some others) the container of the message was rendered with a HUGE width (approx. 100,000px, for no obvious reason of course) of which the padding took ca. 1000px on each side.

As the content was centered, it was simply out of view for the person opening the message (no normal person has such a wide screen)

I replaced the 1% padding with a 3px padding and that solved the problem.

Below is a screen shot to show the problem, rendered in IE8. The solution is to change the padding as described above.

[image]